# Heroku container deployment as a worker not starting

Tags: docker, heroku

I have set up a Docker container to run as a worker in Heroku. I'm using this simple heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    worker: Dockerfile
```

since I want it to run the CMD during the release. The log shows it's deployed correctly:

```
2019-03-05T15:13:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user jmerelo@ugr.es
2019-03-05T15:14:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-05T15:14:29.292628+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f9dd7726 by user jmerelo@ugr.es
2019-03-05T15:14:29.292628+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user jmerelo@ugr.es
```

And the worker tab in the dashboard shows correctly the CMD instruction in the Dockerfile:

```
 worker /bin/sh -c ./create-user-rmq.sh\ \&\&\ celery\ -A\ PlatziTareas\ worker\ --loglevel\=debug\ \&\ ./cliente-con-celery.py
```

However, it does not seem to be running; it's not showing anything in the logs beyond the created release. Any idea of what can be going on here? Just in case, the environment variable has been also set, but it's not showing any of the output that it shows in those cases.

*Note*: the whole application is [in this repo](https://github.com/JJ/slack-bot-platzi), but I am not sure this is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate a dyno after deployment, as indicated [in this article](https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/deploying-docker-to-heroku-344985da5426):

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```